# What is the difference between the two syntax?

Tags: c

Why

`(a?b:c)=5;`

in 'C' shows lvalue required while

`*(a?&b:&c)=5;`

is perfectly fine? What is the difference between the two?

Assuming a=1, for first case, it gives b=5 and second case it gives, `*(&b)=5`.`

What i am not able to understand is: what difference does it make if we write `b=5` or `*(&b)=5`?

Comment: @Ashwyn: You need to explain exactly what you didn't understand from the answers to the duplicate that you linked to. As far as I can tell a careful reading show provide all the information that you need. If if isn't you need to post a question that concentrates only on what you need to know. E.g. "What is an lvalue and why can't I assign to something that isn't one?".

Comment: @CharlesBailey: All i am not able to understand is the difference in assignment in b=5, and *(&b)=5, and i could understand it from the FAQ mentioned for which i asked it here

Comment: @Ashwyn: Then post that as a question and remove all the references to the conditional operator as that is just a distraction. For reference, there is no practical difference to `b=5` and `*(&b)=5`; they do the same thing.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: But i can't seem to understand the difference when it is used with the ternary operator, and that's what i don't understand. Please clarify!

Comment: @Ashwyn: The result of a ternary operator is never an lvalue in C so you cannot assign to it. This was explained in the duplicate link to your previous question.

Comment: So are we not assigning to *(&b) in *(a?&b:&c)=5 which is the same as b as you said?

Comment: @Ashwyn: I don't understand that question. The result of applying the dereference operator (`*`) to a pointer value is an lvalue even if the pointer value is not itself an lvalue. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Ok, got you! What i deduce is ternary operator returns the value of the variable. While here we are dereferencing the value returned which is the address of b, and this is where 5 gets stored! So (a?*(&b):*(&c)) is not quite the same as *(a?&b:&c)! Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what difference does it make if we write b=5 or *(&b)=5?

The second one gets a pointer to `b` and then dereferences that pointer, storing 5 into the obtained pointer.

However, your question seems to be ignoring the *real* question: why it works in the second case but not the first. And that has to do with expressions in C and how they're dealt with.

The result of the `?:` operator is a value; specifically, it is an *rvalue*. Loosely defined, an rvalue is a value that can't go on the left-hand side of an assignment. They are so named because they're values that go on the right-hand side of an assignment. For example, the expression "5" is an rvalue expression. You can't do `5 = 40;` that's nonsense.

A named variable is an lvalue. You can put an lvalue on the left-hand side of an equation. The expression `a` is an lvalue expression (assuming that `a` is a variable name that is in scope).

However, the expression `(a + b)` is an *rvalue expression*, not an lvalue. And with good reason; you can no more do `(a + b) = 30;` than you could `(5 + 10) = 30;`.

The result of the `?:` operator is an rvalue expression, just as with the `+` operator above. This explains why `(a?b:c) = 5;` doesn't work; you're trying to assign a value to an rvalue expression. That's illegal.

Now, let's look at the second case. We know that `?:` results in an rvalue expression. Now, that explains what the classification of the expression is, but what about the *type* of the expression's result? Well, assuming that `b` and `c` are both `int`s, the *type* of `(a?b:c)` is also `int`.

However, when you do `(a?&b:&c)`, the type of this expression is *`int*`*, not `int`. It is a *pointer* to an integer. It's an rvalue expression of type "pointer to `int`." It will return either the address of `b`, or the address of `c`.

When you have an `int*`, and you dereference it with the `*` operator, what do you get? You get an ***lvalue expression*** of type `int`. Since `(a?&b:&c)` is an rvalue expression of type `int*`, if you dereference it, you will get an lvalue expression of type `int`. This lvalue will refer to either `b` or `c`, depending on the contents of `a`.

To put it simply, it works exactly like this:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
if(a)
  ptr = &b;
else
  ptr = &c;

*ptr = 5;
```

You get a pointer, which could point to any particular memory location, then you store something in the location being pointed to. It's that simple.